# Intersecting nested lists using a lambda function

Tags: python, list, lambda

I would like to intersect two nested lists:

```
source = [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six'], ['seven', 'eight', 'nine']]
target = [['three', 'whatever'], ['four', 'whatever'], ['whatever', 'whatever']]
```

So I can return the lists in `source` where intersections were found:

```
result = [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

How can I do this using `lambda`?

Comment: when you say intersect, what exactly do you mean? You mean one item of the sublist should be in one item of the other sublist? Or should it be in the "same" sublist (same index)?

Comment: @MSeifert yes, one item of the sublist should have the same item of the other sublist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *set* to check if there is any intersection between elements:

```
[s for s in source if any(set(s) & set(t) for t in target)]
# [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

---

This could be slightly more efficient if convert the *target* to a list of sets before hand:

```
target_set = [set(t) for t in target]
[s for s in source if any(set(s) & t for t in target_set)]
```

When saying `lambda`, maybe you need a `filter` function:

```
filter(lambda s: any(set(s) & t for t in target_set), source)
```

Or in python 3:

```
list(filter(lambda s: any(set(s) & t for t in target_set), source))
```

---

It seems like your logic is equivalent to the following as @JohnColeman commented:

```
target_set = {j for i in target for j in i}    
filter(lambda s: set(s) & target_set, source)

# [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['four', 'five', 'six']]
```

Comment: "This could be slightly more efficient if convert the target to a list of sets before hand" -- why not convert it into a single set by forming the union?

Comment: @JohnColeman Ahh, I think you are right, the logic seems to be like this.

Comment: `target_set = reduce(lambda s, b: s|b, [set(t) for t in target], set())` and then `[s for s in source if set(s) & target_set]`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) in the `lambda` combined with a filter:

```
list(filter(lambda s: set(s).difference(*target) != set(s), 
            source))
```

This will keep any list that contains at least one item that is in any of the `target`-lists.

Or if you don't like `set`s you can do the checks explicitly:

```
list(filter(lambda s: any(item in sublist for sublist in target for item in s), 
            source))
```